# Android SplashFragment is not working with FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    }

    public void runSplash() {
        SplashFragment splashFragment = new SplashFragment();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, splashFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can fix the `fragmentManager` line by `fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();`. And by the looks of it, it appears `SplashFragment` does not really exist.

Answer (score 0):

runSplash() never gets called in your code